# How to style form use css

Tags: css

Hi I'm confuse how to make this

[image]

in my form input:

```
<input type="text" class="span2">
```

small background on corner right bottom.
Thank you for help

Comment: Please show us some code you've tried.

Comment: make a triangle with absolute positioning

Comment: If you use a background, the image will resize as you resize the textarea.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar: could you help to create some code?

Comment: @Lena Queen Here's a rough idea: http://jsfiddle.net/7dv2G/

Comment: @LenaQueen: Please show us **your** effort, what you have tried, before asking us to put some effort of our own.

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vLdcB/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `background` css property.

```
background: url('/img.png') no-repeat right bottom;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
```

**[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/vLdcB/1/)**

Comment: @LenaQueen always welcome...Glad to help you.